# Authorize GAE server to access Cloud SQL Instance

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Iv'e created a Cloud SQL instance and I want to access it through my Google App Engine server (node.js) I have applied all the necessary details but it seems like only if I authorize my ip address it works..
my question: is it possible to authorize request from the server to Cloud SQL without whitelisting my ip?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information for us to help. Are you using App Engine Standard or Flexible environment? Are you trying to connect from your local machine or from your app deployed on Google infrastructure? Have you followed the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine for your setup?

Comment: Im using the standard environment and Im try to access it from the deployed app. Iv'e tried to follow the link above on node.js but didn't really got what do I need to do

Comment: Can you follow the link https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine and start building your project from there? Then tell us what errors you find. By the way, in App Engine you don't need to whitelist any IP.

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez Iv'e tried following this example but when I try to connect to the database it seems like I don't have the permission to do so unless I whitelist my ip in the authorization section in gae

Comment: Show us all the errors you receive please. Make sure you are following the nodejs version step by step: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-sql

Comment: I don't have to use knex right?

Comment: According to item 4 in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-sql#setting_connection_strings_and_adding_a_library you have to. I have just deployed an example and it works. Also try to do it in cloud shell. It's very straightforward

Comment: well what if i don't want to use a query builder? I just wanna use mysql pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I found a solution without using knex,
basically I had to add this if statement

```
if (process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    pool.socketPath = `/cloudsql/${process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`;
  }
```

works smoothly

Comment: Great. I am glad you found a solution. Cheers